Subtract data from table
I have two tables with similar data, but with different granularity. I want to subtract data from table #1 (p) data from table #2 (t). But there is a column for which preliminary calculations are needed (bounce_rate) for correct result. I need to get bounces (sessions * bounce_rate) and then do the reverse operation (after subtract).
Query:
with t as(
  select 
    pre.property_id, 
    pre.date_hour_minute, 
    sum(pre.sessions) as sessions, 
    sum(pre.bounces) as bounces, 
    sum(pre.total_users) as total_users, 
    sum(pre.user_engagement_duration) as user_engagement_duration 
  from 
    (
      select 
        dhmusr.property_id, 
        dhmusr.date_hour_minute, 
        dhmusr.sessions, 
        dhmusr.sessions * dhmusr.bounce_rate as bounces, 
        dhmusr.total_users, 
        dhmusr.user_engagement_duration 
      from 
        google_analytics_ga4.date_hour_minute_utm_sessions_report dhmusr
    ) as pre 
  group by 
    1, 
    2
), 
p as (
  select 
    dhmsr.property_id, 
    dhmsr.date_hour_minute, 
    dhmsr.sessions, 
    dhmsr.sessions * dhmsr.bounce_rate as bounces, 
    dhmsr.total_users, 
    dhmsr.user_engagement_duration 
  from 
    google_analytics_ga4.date_hour_minute_sessions_report dhmsr
) 
select 
  p.property_id, 
  p.date_hour_minute, 
  p.sessions - t.sessions as sessions, 
  (p.bounces - t.bounces)/ p.sessions as bounce_rate, 
  p.bounces - t.bounces as bounces, 
  p.total_users - t.total_users as total_users, 
  p.user_engagement_duration - t.user_engagement_duration as user_engagement_duration 
from 
  p 
  join t on p.property_id = t.property_id 
  and p.date_hour_minute = t.date_hour_minute


How is that possible? What did I miss?

1/6 != 0,0666..
I also simply run this query:
select 
dhmsr.property_id,
dhmsr.date_hour_minute,
dhmsr.sessions,
dhmsr.sessions * dhmsr.bounce_rate as bounces,
dhmsr.bounce_rate,
dhmsr.bounce_rate/dhmsr.sessions as bounce_rate_new,
dhmsr.total_users,
dhmsr.user_engagement_duration
from google_analytics_ga4.date_hour_minute_sessions_report dhmsr

And I got this:

bounce_rate and bounce_rate_new should be almost equals, no? Seems like, I don't see any stupid mistake.

Please do not post screenshots.  What you missed is that you are dividing by p.sessions instead of p.sessions - t.sessions.
